# Implementing dijkstra's algorithm in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet set up with a bunch of distances to different restaurants. For simplicity, lets say all of column `A` has the restaurant names / code (Say a code is a number, 2 through XXX). Then, in `B` through `XXX - 1` there is a number displaying the distance between the restaurant in `A`, and the restaurant whose code is the column number.

How would I go about implementing dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path given 2 user-entered inputs?

See below for a screenshot of the example spreadsheet:
[image: Screenshot of the Spreadsheet]

Comment: Write it in pure VBA. The input could be a start node, a target node, and a 2-dimensional VBA array of distances and the return value could either be the distance or perhaps the shortest path itself. The layout of your spreadsheet is to some extent irrelevant when you are implementing Dijkstra. It only matters when you need to call your VBA function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you would do is to write VBA code that loops over all the data that have distance information and store them in a proper graph data structure. I am not sure whether your data represent an undirected graph or whether it is just coincidence that you have a lower triangle matrix representation.

Anyway, after having transformed the data in a proper VBA data structure you could take an existing solution and make it work with your data structure. Or, in the first place, you make sure that the data structure fits to an existing solution. You can find a VBA Dijkstra implementation [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/User:Klever).

If you want to implement it yourself, you can find many illustrative examples on the net, like [here](http://optlab-server.sce.carleton.ca/POAnimations2007/DijkstrasAlgo.html), to help you understand the algorithm itself.